# How to efficiently fill a np.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I try to fill in data into a numpy array. However, for higher indexes it takes more and more time. Why?

And how can I prevent that?
I already have created the arrays in the final dimensions...

```
import random
import numpy as np

# p = [ ... 2200 values in a python list ... ]

iterations = 1000
max_draws = len(p)-1

percentiles = np.zeros(max_draws)
money_list = np.zeros(iterations)

invest = 100
for k in range(1,max_draws):
    print(k)
    for j in range(0,iterations):
        money_list[j] = (invest * np.random.choice(p, k)).sum()

    percentiles[k] = np.percentile(money_list, 5)
```

I have a list of factors `p` that represent gains from a trade at the stock market. Now I want to find out how many of that trades I must do (taken from the list of possible trades) so that with 95 % propability I make money and not lose money (given that if I make all the trades I make money and not lose it).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your code has a redundant `for` loop: `for i in range(0,k):   index = random.randint(0, len(p)-1)`.

Comment: You can replace `for i in range(0,k): index = random.randint(0, len(p)-1); money_list[j] = invest * p[index]` with `money_list[j] = invest * np.random.choice(p)`

Comment: Sorry, I had missed a line: "money += invest * p[index]" that makes the for i loop non redundant.

Comment: @mrCarnivore still redundant. see my comment above. Also avoid loops with numpy array. All your loops are vectorizable. Maybe you can explain what you are trying to do and we can help better

Comment: @Ehsan: I had another bug in my code. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: @mrCarnivore you still can get rid of the loop. `money_list[j] = (k+1)*invest + np.random.choice(p, k).sum()`

Comment: @Ehsan: No. ´p´ is a list of factors. So I do have to multiply them with the invest value to get the returns...

Comment: @mrCarnivore oh my bad, read it as plus sign. You still can do it: `money_list[j] = invest + (invest*np.random.choice(p, k)).sum()` along with all other loops. But it is hard to help further without clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ehsan: Thank you that works as well. However, this does not fix my original problem. Still it takes more and more time if I want to change higher index values of 'percentiles'. Is that normal with np.arrays? I cannot imagine it is...

Comment: Yes it seems it is possible to make it faster. loops are very slow with numpy. I would suggest editing post to a more clear problem (than convert code to more efficient) so we can help better. You only have one loop left, right?

Comment: Referencing or changing the last item of an array is no different from accessing the first (time wise).  But it takes time, especially when done many times.  Where possible you want to use the builtin numpy methods that work with the whole array.  If you must work element by element you might be better of using lists.

Comment: @Ehsan: I have two loops left. See current edit.

Comment: @hpaulj: If I run the program it takes longer and longer between each output of 'print(k)'. Why is that? That does make no sense to me...

Comment: You should also convert `p` to numpy array once, this will speed up, i.e. `p = np.array(p)`.

Comment: @Arty: Wow that does speed up things considerably! Thanks!

Comment: @mrCarnivore Posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64212740/941531) about how to speed up even more, `4.18x` times more, using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all suggested improvements one more very efficient improvement can be done.

If you don't mind installing and using quite heavy extra python pip package [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (by `python -m pip install numba`) then you can improve speed considerably, like in next code.

Numba is designed to precompile Python's functions to efficient machine code, also it is designed to be used with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). It converts python loops to fast [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) code and compiles it using [LLVM](https://llvm.org/).

Next code achieves speedups of `4.18x` times for `2199` iterations of outer loop like in your code, and up to `100x` times speedup for few 5-20 iterations. All 2199 iterations for your case using Numba where done in 90 second on my slow PC.

[Try next code here online too!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64211377#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy numba
import random, numpy as np, numba, timeit

p = np.random.random((2200,)) # or do p = np.array(p) if p is a list

iterations = 1000
max_draws = len(p) - 1

invest = 100

def do_regular(hi):
    percentiles = np.zeros(max_draws)
    money_list = np.zeros(iterations)

    for k in range(1, hi):
        for j in range(0,iterations):
            money_list[j] = (invest * np.random.choice(p, k)).sum()

        percentiles[k] = np.percentile(money_list, 5)
        
    return percentiles, money_list

do_numba  = numba.jit(nopython = True)(do_regular)
            
do_numba(2) # Pre-compile, heat up
for hi in [8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, max_draws]: #max_draws
    tr = timeit.timeit(lambda: do_regular(hi), number = 1)
    tn = timeit.timeit(lambda: do_numba(hi), number = 1)
    print(str(hi).rjust(4), 'regular', round(tr, 3), 'sec')
    print(str(hi).rjust(4), 'numba', round(tn, 3), 'sec, speedup', round(tr / tn, 2), flush = True)
```

outputs:

```
   8 regular 0.604 sec
   8 numba 0.005 sec, speedup 131.2
  16 regular 1.296 sec
  16 numba 0.013 sec, speedup 101.36
  32 regular 2.672 sec
  32 numba 0.034 sec, speedup 78.18
  64 regular 5.515 sec
  64 numba 0.113 sec, speedup 48.87
 128 regular 11.3 sec
 128 numba 0.374 sec, speedup 30.19
 256 regular 23.758 sec
 256 numba 1.35 sec, speedup 17.59
 512 regular 51.767 sec
 512 numba 5.086 sec, speedup 10.18
2199 regular 376.327 sec
2199 numba 90.104 sec, speedup 4.18
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about numba before. Will have to do some reading to fully understand how to use it. Did not even need to install it. It was already on my system. (came with pycharm?)

Comment: @mrCarnivore It is not that popular as other scientific packages, because it is not doing any useful computational things except speeding up code, hence not many use or know it. But probably it is sometimes coupled with NumPy, hence you had it on your system, it is mainly was designed to speed up numpy code.